# Query regarding overlapping polygons

Tags: overlapping-features

I have one shapefile which has 78765 polygons of different year, path and row.
I want to remove the polygons which has more than 80% of overlap.
Can somebody help me because symmetrical difference, find identical did not work for me.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?